# 4GL ABL Openedge loop through handle?

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge, 4gl

here is my current code

```
def var hbTT as handle.

for each Cust:
  hbTT:buffer-create().
  assign
    hbTT::Name    = Cust.Name
    hbTT::address = Cust.Address.
end.
```

now what I want to do is to loop through hbtt. How can I do that?

I tried

```
for each hbTT:
  /* Do something */
end.
```

the error I get is

> unknown or ambiguous table hbTT. (725)

thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You won't be able to do a loop that way, as for each requires a static name.
Instead, try this:

```
DEFINE VARIABLE hQuery AS HANDLE      NO-UNDO.

create query hQuery.
hQuery:set-buffers(hbtt).
hquery:query-prepare('for each tt'). /* <-- Where tt is the original buffer name */
hquery:query-open().

hquery:get-first().
do while not hquery:query-off-end:
    disp hbtt::name hbtt::address .
    hquery:get-next().
end.
```

Comment: Thank you Exactly what I need